# Can not test load jms/Tibco ems using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, tibco-ems

I am trying to use Jmeter to test performance of tibco ems service, I use JMS point-to-point and JMS publisher, but not successfully. And got the below error:

> Response message: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Not permitted:
>   invalid name or password [Root exception is
>   javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: invalid name or password]

I don't know why because I used the correct usename/password Please see my images for setting in two cases:[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Tibco EFTL Java client library](https://www.tibco.com/products/tibco-messaging/downloads):

```
package com.tibco.eftl;

import com.tibco.eftl.impl.WebSocketConnection;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Properties;

public class EFTL {
    public static final String PROPERTY_USERNAME = "user"; // <------ this is the correct property name
    public static final String PROPERTY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String PROPERTY_TIMEOUT = "timeout";
    public static final String PROPERTY_CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
    public static final String PROPERTY_NOTIFICATION_TOKEN = "notification_token";
    public static final String PROPERTY_AUTO_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS = "auto_reconnect_attempts";
    public static final String PROPERTY_AUTO_RECONNECT_MAX_DELAY = "auto_reconnect_max_delay";
    public static final String PROPERTY_DURABLE_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String PROPERTY_DURABLE_KEY = "key";
    public static final String DURABLE_TYPE_SHARED = "shared";
    public static final String DURABLE_TYPE_LAST_VALUE = "last-value";
    private static KeyStore trustStore;
```

So my expectation is that you need to change your `username` property to `user` and your scenario should start working normally.

Just in case check out [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article for more information on message queues load testing with JMeter